# Hide div element with jQuery, when mouse isn't moving for a period of time?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, menu, show-hide

I have a broadcasting video site, with a menu, which should be hidden, when mouse isn't moving for a while (lets say 10 seconds). As well, it should appears back, with mouse move. What is the best way to perform that, by using css and jQuery? 
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Do you get mouse move events when the mouse moves over the video? Or are you using a plugin which stops all of those events bubbling up? If you can't best to use whatever plugin (I'm assuming Flash) is showing the video to handle the menu too.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Take a look at the [`mousemove`](http://api.jquery.com/mousemove/) event. You can try something like this:

```
var i = null;
$("#element").mousemove(function() {
    clearTimeout(i);
    $("#menu").show();
    i = setTimeout(function () {
        $("#menu").hide();
    }, 10000);
}).mouseleave(function() {
    clearTimeout(i);
    $("#menu").hide();  
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/AMn9v/6/

Comment: Great, that's what I looked for! I was looking at mousemove event, but just couldn't figure out, how to put a Timeout in it. Thank you a lot!

Comment: For extra polish, the JQuery `fadeOut(1000)` and `fadeIn(100)` work well in place of `hide()` and `show()`. Times are examples.