# jquery timeout solution?

Tags: javascript, jquery, timeout

Let say (i simplify) i have 4 div with content...
i like to fade/hide them if the mouse is left unmove for 2 sec
and when the mouse mouve again... let quikly make everything appear again...

how simple is that to make in jquery ?

i am not really used to timetout and mouse.. more css used to !

---

I google for the "concept" and find that : [Hide div element with jQuery, when mouse isn't moving for a period of time?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4305726/hide-div-element-with-jquery-when-mouse-isnt-moving-for-a-period-of-time)

i will investigate if work !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need to create a run-a-way timer which restarts on every mousemove.

```
$(document).bind('mousemove', function() {
    var $somediv = $('#somediv');

    return function() {
        if(!$somediv.is(':visible'))
            $somediv.fadeIn('slow');

        this.tID && clearInterval(this.tID);
        this.tID = setTimeout(function() {
            $somediv.fadeOut('slow');
        }, 2000);
    };
}());
```

**Demo**: http://www.jsfiddle.net/ByrKk/

Comment: Use clearTimeout and you should clear tID when the timeout expires, so you don't clear it after it's expired.  Also, it's quite inefficient to clear and setTimeout on every mousemove, but it's a quick solution.

Comment: inefficient ?!, what would be the "better" solution ?

Comment: your exact code implement into my page dont work.. : http://aevm.ca/test1.php do you have an idea  why ?

Answer (score 0):

Final solution... and a easy one : http://paulirish.com/2009/jquery-idletimer-plugin/
the jquery.idle-timer.js